# Static global variable cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, jar

I have generated a stub in which it is trying to access Static global variable defined in Jar File as shown below.

```
generatedSetterHelperImpl(cancelWaybill, CANCELWAYBILL$0, 0, org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.KIND_SETTERHELPER_SINGLETON);
```

Here it gives error "cannot be resolved" for `KIND_SETTERHELPER_SINGLETON` variable. When i decompiled XmlObjectBase.class file i found that `KIND_SETTERHELPER_SINGLETON` is defined. But in eclipse F3 for XmlObjectBase does not show `KIND_SETTERHELPER_SINGLETON`.

[image]

Snippet of decompiled file(XmlObjectBase.class) is as shown below.

```
public abstract class XmlObjectBase
implements TypeStoreUser,
Serializable,
XmlObject,
SimpleValue {
    public static final short MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER = 1;
    public static final short MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER = 1;
    public static final short KIND_SETTERHELPER_SINGLETON = 1;
    public static final short KIND_SETTERHELPER_ARRAYITEM = 2;
    public static final ValidationContext _voorVc;
```

Well, i am able to access `MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER` variable.

```
Any Idea on this.
```

Comment: is this `KIND_SETTERHELPER_SINGLETON` variable the only one you cannot access?

Comment: Yes, KIND_SETTERHELPER_SINGLETON is only variable that i cannot accesss.

Comment: I'd bet that you decompiled some jar different from the one loaded from Eclipse. Are you sure you decompiled the `home/openbravo/workspace/obdev/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar`?

Comment: I'm damn sure i compiled same jar, wait, i'll tell you some unexpected behaviour of that jar. I created different java project in same workspace and than imported same jar and stub, stub  was able resolve KIND_SETTERHELPER_SINGLETON. The only problem is that variable is not able to resolve in my project(Enterprise).

Answer (score 6):

Is ancient history but here is my encounter with this.

I had to refactor an app for a client and I started running the tests.
First test, first error, NoSuchMethodError
generatedSetterHelperImpl(Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;IS)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;

In Intellij I had xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar and same code deplyed on weblogic worked just fine.

Discovered where xmlsbeans is used, in the projects of my client.
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.apache.xmlbeans

In my case it was in a test dependency test-jartest

All I had to do, was to exclude from pom.xml xmlbeans-2.3.0, add 2.6.0 and the day was saved.